# How do I get jQuery to return a table row element when using "this?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablerow

I'm using an asp.net list view control and within it I'm building a table element.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr class="header">
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceHolder runat="server">
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr onclick="RowClick();">
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I'm calling a javascript function behind the row click.

```
function RowClick() {
    var tds = $(this).children('td');
}
```

My problem is that `$(this)` within my RowClick() function doesn't return a `tr` element, it's returning the entire window instead.  How can I achieve this?  Am I approaching the situation wrong?  Is this not possible and I'm chasing ghosts?  Thanks!  Forgive my markup, still haven't quite gotten the hang of it yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: This is not valid html.

Comment: @SLaks I've been able to figure all those things in the link you provided but I never knew that page existed before today lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to pass a custom execution context for the handler invokation, you use [Function.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to do this

```
<tr onclick="RowClick.call(this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery? hm, let me see.

```
jQuery("tr").click(RowClick);
```

Regards.

Comment: Change the selector to the needs.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very "jQuery'esque" in terms of handling the code.  A more "proper" way would be to do something like this:

```
<tr class="row-click">
```

and in your javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $(".row-click").each(function(){
        $(this).on("click",function(){
            var tds = $(this).children('td');
            //Code goes here...
        });
    });
});
```

alternatively, if you want to keep the "RowClick" function, you could do:

```
$(function(){
    $(".row-click").each(function(){
        $(this).on("click",function(){
            RowClick($(this));
        });
    }
});
function RowClick(element){
    var tds = $(element).children('td');
    //Code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that you are double-wrapping a jQuery object in `RowClick()`. This could lead to varying issues expecially when applying effects like fading or CSS transitions.

Comment: Double wrapping doesn't cause any issues AFAIK, although I'd love to be proven wrong and see a working example of how it can cause issues, however it does certainly take a bit of a performance hit - http://jsperf.com/check-jquery-wrap/2 .  Personally, I prefer to double wrap in that case so that the function is flexible in case a developer sees "element" later on down the road and passes in the raw dom element instead of the jquery wrapped element.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against mucking up your HTML with JS calls and jQuery handles this beautifully:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // create the function
    function RowClick(target){
        var tds = target.children('td');

        // another option :)
        var tds = target.find('td');
    }

    // listen for a <tr> to get clicked within the <table> -> <ItemTemplate> combo and pass the <tr> target to the function
    $('table ItemTemplate').on('click', 'tr', function(){
        RowClick($(this));
    });

});
```

Comment: You're mucking up the JavaScript with code that is far more verbose than necessary. :P And I really don't think `ItemTemplate` is part of the rendered HTML. Not sure... but pretty sure.

Comment: @cookiemonster Idk about `<ItemTemplate>` since I've never done ASP programming so you may very well be right. Although I would have to STRONGLY disagree with you on your `mucking up js` statement because it has far more benefits than drawbacks. Imagine if OP is creating 100 `<tr onclick="RowClick();">` tags. That is 23 bytes ( ` onclick="RowClick();"` ) x 100 `<tr>` of excess, redundant code which amounts to 2,300 extra bytes per page load. The additional JS is ~86 bytes. It is likely that these rows are also dynamic so that is 2,300 fewer bytes that the server has to process per visitor.

Comment: There's always give and take. If there are that many, then I'd suggest event delegation would be the preferred solution whether inline or in JS. If inline, they'll be gzipped down to practically nothing. Either way, one advantage is that the handler is available immediately, which can be important in certain situations where you just mustn't have that latency. Not saying inline handlers are right everywhere. Just saying they shouldn't be so broadly dismissed.